# Analyse flac files in folder and delete all files with a bitrate under 950kbps

Tags: flac

I'm looking for a simple shell command that analyses all flac files in a folder and deletes all files that have a lower bitrate than 950kbps.
Now I have to fire up Clementine, browse to the folder, sort the files and delete manually. That's all I use Clementine for, which is overkill I think.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no simple command to carry out such an operation. However a small script that browses the files in a folder can do the trick.

First thing first, we need a command line utility to get the bit rate of the files. I use `mediainfo` (*mediainfo* package on Debian). Other utilities can also do the job very well. Once installed, the following script lists all the FLAC files in the folder with a bit rate lower than 950 kbps.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for flacfile in *.flac; do
    [ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*' | sed 's/\s//g') -lt 950 ] && echo "$flacfile"                                                                                            
done
```

If it suits you, just replace the `echo` command by the `rm` command to proceed the file deletion:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for flacfile in *.flac; do
    [ $(mediainfo "$flacfile" | grep 'Bit rate' | grep -oi '[0-9].[0-9]*' | sed 's/\s//g') -lt 950 ] && rm "$flacfile"                                                                                            
done
```

#### Explanation

- the `for` loops browses all the `.flac` files in the directory;
- `mediainfo` displays all the information about the FLAC file and gives it to the first `grep` command;
- the first `grep` selects the bit rate line and gives it to the second `grep`;
- the second `grep` selects in this line only the numbers. The `.` in `[0-9].[0-9]*` deals with space thousand separator (in `1␣050` for example);
- `sed` removes the space thousand separator if needed;
- finally `[ ... -lt 950 ]` checks if the bit rate is less than 950 kbps and if it is true the `rm` command removes the file.

Comment: That is absolutely spectacular, thank you so much :D That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)